# Installing obfs4proxy on Centos / Fedora

Tags: obfs4proxy

Have cloned the git library for obfs4 from https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4

Have installed go version go1.11.5 linux/amd64.

I am trying to follow the Readme.md build instructions, but the build fails with Error 404 file not found:

```
go build -o obfs4proxy/obfs4proxy ./obfs4proxy
go: finding gitlab.com/yawning/utls.git v0.0.10-1
go: gitlab.com/yawning/utls.git@v0.0.10-1: git fetch -f https://gitlab.com/yawning/utls refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /root/work/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/f923860f723f34e4b0e4888426f2ddac74b64cf389f0d13e9bf5cc235784502b: exit status 128:
        error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404
        fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
go: error loading module requirements
```

I cannot get past this point.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that GitLab (or `gitlab.com/yawning/utls` specifically) isn’t being blocked? Can you clone the repository manually?

Comment: No I cannot git clone that URL.  That also gives a 404 error.  I can (and did) git clone https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4, but I don't know where to go from there.  I can also get to https://gitlab.com/yawning/utls from a browser.

Comment: If no one replies here, this might be a better question for the SuperUser stack exchange.

Comment: Try installing a newer version of GIT client. For example, as described in this [article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7/). After that I was able to build a binary file obfs4proxy.